# How to display a section only in toc?

Tags: formatting, section-titles

I want to create a command `\unsection{title}` (with `title` the title of a new section) with a behavior similar to `\section{title}` but the `title` should only be displayed in the toc. To illustrate my request, here is the version that works for chapters :

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

I tried to do the same by replacing `\@makechapterhead` with `\@makesectionhead` but this didn't work (the title is still displayed).

**How can I produce a similar result as `\unchapter` but with `\section` ?**

EDIT: IMPORTANT - the section create by `\unsection` should be numbered like `\section`.

PS: I'm aware of the solution using `\addcontentsline` but for my comfort, I would prefer a solution similar to `\unchapter`.

Comment: `\newcommand{\unsection}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}` However, how would readers know where to look for the start of this section and link it to the title in the table of contents?

Comment: There is a separator between parts that would be separated by `\unsection`, but I didn't wanted to use `titlesec`to change the layout of sections titles. Thank you

Comment: @egreg Can your suggestion allow the section to b numbered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say something like

```
\newcommand{\unsection}[1]{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\bigskipamount}% or whatever separation you want to use
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
}
```

In context (the `openany` option is only used to show a single picture)

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble % make \@makechapterhead do nothing
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\unsection}[1]{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\bigskipamount}% or whatever separation you want to use
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\unchapter{Test chapter}

\kant[1][1-3]

\unsection{Test section}

\kant[2][1-3]

\unsection{Test section again}

\kant[3][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure how your readers are supposed to interpret this.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Actually I don't need `\par \addvspace{\bigskipamount}` part because what I want it's only the label part of the section. Thank you !